# Can someone explain to me this emu8086 code?

Tags: emu8086

```
mov bx,offset array
dec bx
 mov cx,100
next: inc bx
 cmp [bx],0FFH
 
 loope next
```

can you explain why we ( DEC BX ) AND AGAIN (INC BX ) ?  looking for compelete answer thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decrement bx *before* the loop, then the first instruction in the loop increments bx.

This way, on the first iteration of the loop, bx is again pointing at the beginning of `array`. On the second iteration, it points at the second item, and so on.

It might initially seem more straightforward to do something like:

```
      mov bx, offset array
next: cmp [bx], 0ffh
      inc bx
      loopne next
```

The problem with this is that we're depending on the `cmp` to set the Z flag, which is used by the `loopne` instruction--but the `inc` instruction also affects the Z flag, so this would lose the result from the `cmp`, so the `loopne` wouldn't work correctly any more.

That having been said, this seems to be doing roughly the same thing as `repne scasb` can do:

```
mov di, offset array
mov al, 0ffh
mov cx, 100
repne scasb     ; this instruction implements the entire loop
```

The big difference is that `repne scasb` always searches in an array whose base is given in `es:di`, which can sometimes be clumsy to deal with (e.g., if you're already using `es` to point to something else).

Comment: i understand thx for answer but (DEC) is not in loop and run just 1 time so its for (ZF) ? we doing this

Comment: It's to set bx to just *before* the beginning of the array, so when the `inc bx` in the loop executes the first time, it gets back to the beginning of the array. The Z flag is why you can't move the increment to after the compare.